# Battleship Game - Random Ship Placement

Tags: java

I have to do a Battleship game. The game should have some kind of AI. The AI CAN place ships with a hard coded pattern, but i want to take things a step further and make the ship placement random.

I have implemented a "trial and error" method, where ships get randomly placed on the field with a random rotation, until the algorithm runs out of either ships to be placed or fields to place the ships in. In the second case the recursive implementation allows to try out other ship/field/rotation combos, until the first condition is reached. So to speak: try all possible ship/rotation/field combo's (picked randomly) until you find one valid one, where all ships are placed.

As you can imagine, this is a terrible effort, when it comes to runtime.
The size of the "board" can be 5x5 up to 30x30 with exactly 30% of the fields beeing occupied by a ship.

Now, Runtime isn't my concern for sizes up to 14x14, but then runtime increases so badly, that i have to think of a way to reduce runtime.

Any suggestions? (I would like to get general thinking advice/idea's, not code)

In case, my explenation wasn't enough: Here's the class that tries to place the ships on the field:

```java
public class RandomShipFactory {

    private int size;
    private Game game;
    private ArrayList<Ship> toBeCheckedShips = new ArrayList<Ship>();
    private ArrayList<Position> toBeCheckedPositions = new ArrayList<Position>();
    
    public RandomShipFactory(int size, Game game) {
        this.size = size;
        this.game = game;
        this.toBeCheckedShips.addAll(game.ownBoard.getShips());
        
        for(int i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < this.size; j++) {
                this.toBeCheckedPositions.add(new Position(i,j));
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void makeRandomShipPlacements() {
        this.makeRandomShipPlacements(this.toBeCheckedPositions, this.toBeCheckedShips);
        game.ownBoard.printBoard();
    }
    
    private boolean makeRandomShipPlacements(ArrayList<Position> currentPositions, ArrayList<Ship> currentShips) {
        if(currentPositions.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        
        ArrayList<Position> checkedPositionsInThisRun = new ArrayList<Position>();

        Random r = new Random();
        boolean success = false;
        
        while(!success && !currentShips.isEmpty() && !currentPositions.isEmpty()) {
            int randomPositionIndex = r.nextInt(currentPositions.size());
            Position randomPosition = currentPositions.remove(randomPositionIndex);
            checkedPositionsInThisRun.add(randomPosition);
            
            ArrayList<Ship> currentShipQueue = new ArrayList<Ship>();
            currentShipQueue.addAll(currentShips);
            while(!success && !currentShipQueue.isEmpty()) {
                Ship currentShip = currentShipQueue.remove(0);
                
                boolean shouldRotate = r.nextBoolean();
                if(shouldRotate) {
                    currentShip.rotate();
                }
                
                boolean canPlaceShip = this.game.placeShipOnOwnBoard(currentShip, randomPosition.x, randomPosition.y);
                if(canPlaceShip) {
                    currentShips.remove(currentShip);
                    ArrayList<Position> boxPositions = removeBoxSquarePositions(currentPositions, currentShip, randomPosition);
                    
                    if(currentShips.isEmpty()) {
                        success = true;
                    }else {
                        boolean recursiveSuccess = this.makeRandomShipPlacements(currentPositions, currentShips);
                        if(!recursiveSuccess) {
                            this.game.removeShipFromOwnBoard(currentShip);
                            currentPositions.addAll(boxPositions);
                            currentShips.add(currentShip);
                        }else {
                            success = true;
                        }
                    }
                }else {
                    currentShip.rotate();
                    
                    canPlaceShip = this.game.placeShipOnOwnBoard(currentShip, randomPosition.x, randomPosition.y);
                    if(canPlaceShip) {
                        currentShips.remove(currentShip);
                        ArrayList<Position> boxPositions = removeBoxSquarePositions(currentPositions, currentShip, randomPosition);
                        
                        if(currentShips.isEmpty()) {
                            success = true;
                        }else {
                            boolean recursiveSuccess = this.makeRandomShipPlacements(currentPositions, currentShips);
                            if(!recursiveSuccess) {
                                this.game.removeShipFromOwnBoard(currentShip);
                                currentPositions.addAll(boxPositions);
                                currentShips.add(currentShip);
                            }else {
                                success = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        currentPositions.addAll(checkedPositionsInThisRun);
        return success;
    }
    
    private ArrayList<Position> removeBoxSquarePositions(ArrayList<Position> positionList, Ship ship, Position pos) {
        ArrayList<Position> boxPositions = new ArrayList<Position>();
        for(int i = 0; i < ship.length + 2; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                int nextX, nextY;
                
                switch(ship.getRotation()) {
                case HORIZONTAL:
                    nextX = pos.x - 1 + i;
                    nextY = pos.y - 1 + j;
                    break;
                case VERTICAL:
                    nextX = pos.x - 1 + j;
                    nextY = pos.y - 1 + i;
                    break;
                default:
                    nextX = pos.x - 1 + j;
                    nextY = pos.y - 1 + i;
                    break;
                }
                
                if(nextX >= 0 && nextX < this.size && nextY >= 0 && nextY < this.size) {
                    Position currentPosition = Position.findPosInList(positionList, nextX, nextY);
                    if(currentPosition != null) {
                        positionList.remove(currentPosition);
                        boxPositions.add(currentPosition);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return boxPositions;
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't this better suited on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: it probably would be faster if you will record position of placed ship and remove it from random posibilities then also when position will be randomized check if it's possible to place it including length of a ship etc. And as @a_local_nobody said it's working code so it's better for codereview

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i will post this on codereview (didn't know that existed).

@Szprota21 That is exactly what's happening (not every ship gets tested on every position, it depends on placed ships in current recursive "path", check code for "currentShips" and "currentPositions")

Answer (score 2):

Multiple things to consider here, where improvement can take place:

1. **This point is INVALID, because the OP has actually accounted for that. But this is still a basic thing to keep in mind:** NEVER try to hit positions with random addresses. As soon as the field has a few ships, this will decrease speed drastically. In addition, 'random' functions can be really really slow, depending on their implementation
2. a) Your code is also slow because you search items in linear lists, so in average your additional effort will be `(list size) / 2`. Use HashMaps or TreeMaps or HeapMaps, or their `Set` version.
3. b) Your code uses `remove(anyIndex)`. In `ArrayList`s, this will start to copy (on average) half of the array data to another position on every call.

- And it does not play a role, whether you 'pop' from the very top (index 0) or not.
- Worst of all, you use this `remove()` in loops, exploding your runtime.
- Use an unstable removal (order will not be maintained), or `LinkedList`s, or some Map.

3. a) instead of targeting random positions, build a map of ALL available spaces (on a 30x30 board, this will add 900 entries to the hashmap).
   *The advantage of this approach is that build-up is slow, but all other operations are linear or minimized.*

- have a parameter for the size of a ship
- create the HashMap (should be its own method, because we might need this at different locations in the code):
- - iterate over all positions, add the free ones (where you could validly place a ship of required length and rotation) to a hashmap, use coordinates as key
- - alternatively, if you expect coverage to be less than 85%, add ALL positions, then iterate over already placed ships and remove their positions from the HashMap
- - placement collisions for future placements would be possible at this point, but get removed once we hit (y)
- place the ships:
- - x) selecting a random 'index' from a hashmap is a little challenge here, but you'll figure that out
- - y) once you start placing ships, remove all affected positions from the hashmap (include the ship's length and orientation in your calculations)
- - resume at (x)

3. b) extension of that algorithm - improvement for differing sizes

- if you run this algorithm for ships with differing sizes, calculate the available positions for the longest ships first, then you can also re-use the created hashmap for shorter ones. if the hashmap is empty but there are still ships remaining: when you run the 'create hashmap of valid positions' algorithm again, adjust/reduce the searched ship length to the currently required one. (*This then will not be 'truly random' anymore, but random enough that no player will ever realize it. But in cryptography for example, this here would break the algorithm*)
- - this will greatly increase speed while coverage is below ~80%

4. A little hint on switches: use fall-through for combined code blocks:

Your code is

```
        switch(ship.getRotation()) {
            case HORIZONTAL:
                nextX = pos.x - 1 + i;
                nextY = pos.y - 1 + j;
                break;
            case VERTICAL:
                nextX = pos.x - 1 + j;
                nextY = pos.y - 1 + i;
                break;
            default:
                nextX = pos.x - 1 + j;
                nextY = pos.y - 1 + i;
                break;
        }
```

it can easily be reduced to

```
        switch(ship.getRotation()) {
            case HORIZONTAL:
                nextX = pos.x - 1 + i;
                nextY = pos.y - 1 + j;
                break;
            case VERTICAL: // fall-through to default, as VERTICAL seems to be the default^^
            default:
                nextX = pos.x - 1 + j;
                nextY = pos.y - 1 + i;
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

1: I don't quiet understand your point. I get the position via a list of all available positions (opposed to run through all positions and get one that's not occupied).
2: Thanks for that, it's an obvious one. Although this is not the biggest issue for runtime, since i only use the lists to .pop(). But i will change it in future iteration.
3: i don't understand this approach. I should create a HashMap consisting of a Ship and all available positions??

Comment: You are right. I updated my answer accordingly. Hope this clears things up.

Comment: I still don't get how 3 a) will always place ships validly. If the random ships occupie the board in such a way, that a single ship is not placed, but no more "valid" positions are available, the current "combination" is invalid, thus the whole process has to done again, which ultimately leads to the same principle as my approach, despite using HashMaps.
Note: the method Game.placeShipOnOwnBoard() only places a ship, if it's a valid place for it.

Comment: True, my approach is basically the same as yours. Placement is always valid because invalid spaces are taken out of the Map. But this question here is not about algorithm validity, it is about its speed. The way I propose is the fastest I can think of with Java on-board tools. I build up, then eliminate, because this way I do not need either a) *much testing*, or b) *no testing at all* (with coverage less than ~85%). Below ~85% coverage, targeted elimination is **SO MUCH FASTER** than testing. In addition, I can use all the advantages of Maps over Lists. (Except for getting a random element..)

Comment: If you're worried that the board is full and one could not place any more ships, that's a whole different story. The way you are trying will eventually even result in an infinite loop. And you could also use that algorithm with my placement strategy. But if your approach has to reliably work, you would FIRST have to mathematically prove that all ships can be placed on the board, and THEN you could run your placement algorithm. Or you could use a real backtracking algorithm, which will at least provide you with a definite answer, if it's possible (solution for free) or not.

Comment: With 30% of fields beeing occupied, most board/ship(-length) combinations should have at least 1 possible ship placement pattern. I haven't mathematically proven this, since i'm lazy. But I think the worst case scenario is a 29x29 field, with all ships having a length of 2. 29x29 x 0.3 = 252 fields that have to be occupied (int) 252/2 = 126 ships with a length of 2.
To clear things up: 
-> The board is always EXACTLY placed for 30% of the fields
-> The placement of ships can't be changed afterwards (also no ships can be added)
-> The game only has ships with length 5, 4, 3, 2

Comment: The problem i'm concerned about is, the worst case of picked positions. Let's say the positions have been picked like so: https://pasteboard.co/XRXFH09AXKsz.png.
The last ship can't be placed. In my approach, i solve this, by readding all checked positions of the recursive "subpath" to the list. This results in the algorithm either definetly finding a valid placement, or not placing ships at all -> returning false

Comment: I see. As you DEFINE the ships to cover exactly 30%, you can always assume that there's at least 1 possible arrangement. In the other case your algorithm would have to prove it each time, and any random placement will *always prevent* proving. Regarding your algorithm: For each recursive step, you should not use random selection. Together with the high coverage of 30% and the distancing rules, you have few possible and lot of impossible layouts. Chances are you get a lot of repeating trials. In this case I think it's better to create a randomized permutation array that each recursive step uses

Comment: Thanks in advance.
Is the usage of the Random class okay to generate the permutation for that matter? If not, any suggestions on what to use to generate the permutation?

Comment: Nah I think you'd have to write a whole class to satisfy the needs for your permutation. To fit in your code much better, I got another idea: what you need - and permutations would provide - is that per each recursion step, you test ALL available elements/positions (needs to be exhaustive). Don't test twice, and also ensure that every element gets tested. And you'd probably still want some form of randomness, unless each generated map shall look alike.

Comment: To fit your code: instead of selecting random elements, at the beginning of the method `makeRandomShipPlacements` you could shuffle (the remaining) `currentPositions` and then iterate over ALL of them, until the method (or its recursions) reveal a valid solution. This will have the exact same effect as using randomized permutations. But then again, you'd have a serious impact on runtime, in which case you'd have to find a trick to simulate shuffling a lot faster...

Comment: I already check for all (remaining) positions. That's why i create a new List for each recursive run. That is why i'm confused a little bit. All that you describe is already in the code, despite using lists and random, but still the runtime is massive. I just can't imagine that a simple shuffle of the list is so much faster than picking a random one.

Comment: To sum it all up: 1) you nest too many loops in each other. Solution: use multiple Maps or Sets. 2) You search by random indexes. Checked elements will very likely be checked again. This will increase checks from n to n^2/2, resulting in n^2/2 * n/2 (for each recursive step, iterating ships not included). Replace with randomized permutations, or shuffle and iterate over all, interrupt on early success. 3) You should split the method `makeRandomShipPlacements` into 3 methods: one that loops positions, one for ships, one that handles ship placement (duplicate `if(canPlaceShip)` blocks)